# Informix DB is down and not able to start in Linux env

Tags: linux, informix, rhel, rhel7

I am kind of new to using Informix DB, and I hope my basic query does not offend someone in the wrong way.

I have installed Informix DB in one of our Linux environments, and the DB worked fine until yesterday. After a REBOOT I think the Informix DB services did not start automatically, and also when I try and [start](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=informix-stopping-starting-database-server) the services using `oninit`, it just doesn't work.

Currently, the DB is down and I am not sure how to start the Informix DB services in Linux, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is going to be tricky — lots of details are needed.  Which version of Informix would help.  Have you set the environment variables properly?  What messages do you get from `oninit`?  What about in the online log file?  The server will not be started automatically on a reboot by default.  You can arrange for it to happen, but you need to be able to start it manually first, before you try automating it.

Comment: Remember that you will need to have the proper environment (environment variables such as INFORMIXDIR or INFORMIXSERVER) before you run oninit, otherwise the server will not start.  Check the script you use to start the service,.Make sure that is setting the environment, if you are lucky, it will be just that. Informix is quite "resilient" ;).  As Jonathan suggested, posting the last entries of the online log (run 'onstat -m' )may help to understand why it doesn't get up.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I have checked and here is the output

`[user_name@server_name bin]$ echo $INFORMIXDIR`
`/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle`
`[user_name@server_name bin]$ sudo ./oninit`
`Unable to read $INFORMIXDIR (/usr/informix).`

Comment: @jsagrera, thanks for your suggestion. I have checked and here is the output of the `oninit` start-up:

`[user_name@server_name bin]$ echo $INFORMIXDIR`
`/opt/IBM/Informix_Software_Bundle`
`[user_name@server_name bin]$ sudo ./oninit`
`Unable to read $INFORMIXDIR (/usr/informix).`

Comment: The error from the oninit command shows that $INFORMIXDIR is not being preserved by sudo - this is the usual case. I suggest using sudo to start a shell then ensure that INFORMIXDIR and INFORMIXSERVER is correctly set. You may also need the ONCONFIG environment variable - this will refer to a file of the same name in $INFORMIXDIR/etc. If not set it will default to using the "onconfig" or "onconfig.std" files. Whichever file is used it will have an entry MSGPATH that names the online log file. That may have more clues about the problem.

Comment: If you have INFORMIXDIR set, you may also have the rest of varaibles needed in the env, but as Simon said, they are lost when you run "sudo ./oninit". Try without 'sudo'. The oninit binary should have the correct permissions (6754 root:informix) so it will automatically run as root if you just run "oninit -v"